# XML over HTTP with JMS and Spring

Tags: java, web-services, spring, http, jms

I have a legacy HTTP server where I need to send an `XML` file over `HTTP request` (`POST`) using `Java` (not browser) and the server will respond with another `XML` in its `HTTP response`. It is similar to Web Service but there's no WSDL and I have to follow the existing XML structure to construct my XML to be sent.

I have done a research and found an example that matches my requirement [here](http://www.java-tips.org/other-api-tips/httpclient/how-to-send-an-xml-document-to-a-remote-web-server-using-http-5.html). The example uses `HttpClient` from Apache Commons. (There are also other examples I found but they use `java.net` networking package (like `URLConnection`) which is tedious so I don't want to use them).

But it's also my requirement to use `Spring` and `JMS`.

I know from `Spring`'s [reference](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/remoting.html) that it's possible to combine `HttpClient`, `JMS` and `Spring`. My question is, how?

Note that it's **`NOT`** in my requirement to use `HttpClient`. If you have a better suggestion, I'm welcome.

Appreciate it.

---

For your reference, here's the XML-over-HTTP example I've been talking about:

```
/*
 * $Header: 
 * $Revision$
 * $Date$
 * ====================================================================
 *
 *  Copyright 2002-2004 The Apache Software Foundation
 *
 *  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 *  you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 *  You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 *  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 *  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 *  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 *  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 *  limitations under the License.
 * ====================================================================
 *
 * This software consists of voluntary contributions made by many
 * individuals on behalf of the Apache Software Foundation.  For more
 * information on the Apache Software Foundation, please see
 * <http://www.apache.org/>.
 *
 * [Additional notices, if required by prior licensing conditions]
 *
 */

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.InputStreamRequestEntity;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.PostMethod;

/**
 *
 * This is a sample application that demonstrates
 * how to use the Jakarta HttpClient API.
 *
 * This application sends an XML document
 * to a remote web server using HTTP POST
 *
 * @author Sean C. Sullivan
 * @author Ortwin Glück
 * @author Oleg Kalnichevski
 */
public class PostXML {

    /**
     *
     * Usage:
     *          java PostXML http://mywebserver:80/ c:\foo.xml
     *
     *  @param args command line arguments
     *                 Argument 0 is a URL to a web server
     *                 Argument 1 is a local filename
     *
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        if (args.length != 2) {
            System.out.println(
                "Usage: java -classpath <classpath> [-Dorg.apache.commons."+
                "logging.simplelog.defaultlog=<loglevel>]" +
                " PostXML <url> <filename>]");

            System.out.println("<classpath> - must contain the "+
                "commons-httpclient.jar and commons-logging.jar");

            System.out.println("<loglevel> - one of error, "+
                    "warn, info, debug, trace");

            System.out.println("<url> - the URL to post the file to");
            System.out.println("<filename> - file to post to the URL");
            System.out.println();
            System.exit(1);
        }

        // Get target URL
        String strURL = args[0];

        // Get file to be posted
        String strXMLFilename = args[1];
        File input = new File(strXMLFilename);

        // Prepare HTTP post
        PostMethod post = new PostMethod(strURL);

        // Request content will be retrieved directly
        // from the input stream
        // Per default, the request content needs to be buffered
        // in order to determine its length.
        // Request body buffering can be avoided when
        // content length is explicitly specified
        post.setRequestEntity(new InputStreamRequestEntity(
                new FileInputStream(input), input.length()));

        // Specify content type and encoding
        // If content encoding is not explicitly specified
        // ISO-8859-1 is assumed
        post.setRequestHeader(
                "Content-type", "text/xml; charset=ISO-8859-1");

        // Get HTTP client
        HttpClient httpclient = new HttpClient();

        // Execute request
        try {

            int result = httpclient.executeMethod(post);

            // Display status code
            System.out.println("Response status code: " + result);

            // Display response
            System.out.println("Response body: ");
            System.out.println(post.getResponseBodyAsString());

        } finally {
            // Release current connection to the connection pool 
            // once you are done
            post.releaseConnection();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for JMS in this situation, it's designed for asynchronous messaging, not request-response.

What you need is Spring's `RestTemplate`. It is similar to HttpClient but it will handle marshalling for you, if you have a schema.

Comment: I've said I don't have a schema.

Comment: I need to use JMS (asynchronous messaging) as the response might be slow.

Comment: You can't use JMS with HTTP. The two technologies are incompatible.

Comment: why not? I haven't read the article, but I found this: http://weblogs.java.net/blog/kalali/archive/2009/06/jms_over_http_u.html

Comment: That's JMS *over* HTTP. If you have an existing HTTP server that's expecting to serve you some XML, it's not going to magically understand JMS.